# Import cumulocity plugins from own applications

Tags: cumulocity

in the past (somewhere around 8.4) it was possible to include plugins into a "hidden" plugin application for referencing them in other apps.

As André stated, this is still possible to include the plugins in a "hidden" application, but the plugins from the hidden application are not visible to another application during development in the local cumulocity tools runtime.

In an older version of "cumulocity-tools" (Version 2.0.26) the local development server detected all other applications, that exist in the same parent folder during the startup of the development server (`c8y server` command)

Is there a configuration parameter to enable this detection?

Best regards
Meykel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After and including version 2.1.0 of the tool you need to use the flag `-s` or `--searchSibling` to load plugins from sibling apps inside the same parent folder.

Considering this folder structure

```
 - appsFolder
    - appA
    - appB
```

After 2.1.0 version of the cumulocity-tools you need to run this command to use plugins from appB while running the command from `/appsFolder/appA`:

`c8y server -s -u https://acme.cumulocity.com`

You can also find more information on other flags by running `c8y help`.

Comment: Ah, missed that option. Imho it would be nicer if the tools would do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can install applications that are not shown in the app switcher by using the [noAppSwitcher](http://cumulocity.com/guides/web/introduction/index.html#-a-name-manifests-a-manifests) option of the manifest. For sharing common code like Angular services, I recommend to do that at development time using libraries rather than at runtime by referring to files elsewhere. This is a more robust mechanism and provides the opportunity for build-time optimizations.

Comment: Hi André. I've updated the question to include your answer.

Comment: Ahh ok, I don't know. Let me ask. I only know that the "parent folder magic" was confusing to some people, so maybe there was some change.